# Python--converting a column of strings to floats in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to convert a column in a csv file from a string to a float. I keep getting this error message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Is this the proper way to convert  the values from a column in a csv file from strings to floats?

Thanks!

```
with open('temp1.csv', 'rb') as csvfile_temp1:
    reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile_temp1)
    for row in reader1: 
        x = float(row[W_temp])
```

Comment: Where is `W_temp` coming from?

Comment: it's coming from a csv file, which was created from a web scraping of this: http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/44018.txt

Comment: Give full error trace, that help to understand error.

Comment: `row` is a list.  Python is saying that you're trying to index a list with a unicode string, not an integer.  Can you guess what type `W_temp` is, and what type it should be?

Comment: Your `W_temp` might be float, please try to print that.

Comment: Unless its the integer column index of the value you want to convert to float, then it's likely to be an issue.

Comment: I'm probably missing something but the file you reference is a fixed format file, not a CSV file at all. It has multiple spaces between some fields and only one space between others. It seems like just reading lines and splitting them would be more straightforward here.